# Is there is a config setting for tracing WCF calls ?

Tags: wcf

I have simple wcf web service that i contain two endpoint connection 
   soap
   rest

I want to have the ability to save the client request and the my server respond on each session as original xml/json.

How to do it ?

Comment: Your question is pretty broad.  People will probably vote to close it.  Perhaps you are asking if there is a config setting for tracing WCF calls.  If so, you are more likely to get a specific answer.

Comment: Yes, WCF tracing can be enabled in the config:  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wcf/1931/tracing/6310/tracing-settings#t=201701242154513407055